# What is a synonym for "girlfriend"?

Tags: synonyms

I'm in my mid 40s and dating this lady of a similar vintage. I am trying to find a good word to describe our relationship, but "girlfriend" and "boyfriend" seems inappropriate for us. It reminds me of those forty year old guys who say "I'm gittin' down wi ma hommies." It communicates, but it seems out of place.

Perhaps it is the "girl" and "boy" part that bothers me.

Any suggestions for something more appropriate?

Comment: [Jonathan Richman](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AC4p5s0wfgo) redeemed the term for me.

Comment: How about "Darling"? Chiang Kai-shek called Soong May-ling so in his mid-age years.

Comment: btw I am almost 60 and I refer to the woman I am dating as my "girlfriend".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Depending on how comfortable you are with the mixed connotations of the following suggestions:

- lover
- partner
- companion
- mistress
- significant other

You also just refer to her by name which would probably be more polite. Depending on the context you can use the term "dating":

> We are dating.
>
> Sue and I are dating.
>
> We went on a date.
>
> Sue is my date.

---

Edit: Not that there is anything wrong with *girlfriend*. I understand the desire to avoid it but it has its use even amongst older couples.

Comment: +1 for some good options, and for mentioning that *girlfriend* would not be inappropriate (and is often used in this way, even by those much older than the questioner :-).

Comment: Good summary I think. Just to add to the second section: "We are together/going out/seeing each" are also more or less equivalent.

Comment: I'm not sure "mistress" is a good synonym. For me, at least, it has a (somewhat salacious) meaning that goes beyond a connotation.

Comment: Thanks for your input. None of the suggestions really seem on the money, they are either too biological (lover), convey the wrong relationship (SO, partner, and on the other end date) are are too sappy (sweetheart.) I guess we'll just have to muddle by. Thanks for everyone's input. All are good, but MrHen seemed most prolific

Comment: Actually, I would say that "partner" is significantly gaining currency.  I've known (young) people who use this for their own relationships.  I think the gay rights movement might have something to do with it, as many liberal minded people would have no problem with it being misinterpreted to imply same-sex.  I think they would say that such a misinterpretation shows a lack of open-mindedness, or that it the person is uncultured.

Comment: Most of these words mean something rather different from "girlfriend". "lover" is normally understood to imply a sexual relationship. This may or may not be the case in your relationship, and even if so, it probably more information than you want to give in a casual context. "mistress" is normally used to describe the woman that a married man is having an adulterous affair with. Again, I don't know if that applies to you, and if so you probably don't want to announce it publicly.

Comment: (continued) There is an effort to make "partner" an accepted term for any sort of romantic relationship, but today it is mostly used by homosexual couples and people living together without benefit of marriage. If you move in morally liberal circles it may be appropriate; to more conservative people it has undesirable connotations.

Comment: @Jay You're wildly out of date regarding "partner", I feel. Certainly in the UK it's extremely common for couples of any genders and orientations.

Comment: @MartinMcCallion UK usage may be different, and for something like this there might be sub-cultures here in the U.S. that would use the word differently. But I don't recall ever hearing a man refer to a woman whom he was dating, i.e. not living with, as his "partner". I can't insist that it might not be used that way in social or cultural circles different from my own, but I don't recall ever hearing such usage.

Comment: @Jay Yes, I agree that it's a bit closer than "dating" (I personally have an irrational dislike of that term, but never mind). And yes, it does rather imply living together. My point, though, was that it has extended beyond the gay community.

Comment: @MartinMcCallion I did say "and couples living together". I was referring to heterosexual couples there. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: How about "leman" ? It is a bit archaic, but it could work.

Answer (score 7):

How about:

> Sweetheart

A common term to refer to "your lady" i.e. That one, over there, she is my sweetheart.

Kinds of indicate a closeness to your heart :)

Also, if you like something more *passionate*:

> flame

I wouldn't use "mistress", as it has a nuance that doesn't quite describe your relationship, or "partner", as that makes it sound too businesslike.

Answer (score 5):

I personally find the term *[beau](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/beau)* quite endearing and appropriate for men of all ages.  The feminine equivalent is *[belle](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/belle)*, which is also nice.

Or you might like *sweetie*, if that's not too sappy.

Answer (score 4):

For many older dating couples, the terms, *lady friend* and *man friend*, are acceptable. Or even more simply, *lady* and *man*:

> - There's my lady.
> - He's my man.

The most politically correct term might be *signifcant other*, but that could be interpreted by some to mean you are married. *Companion* and *partner* do not seem to work, as they most usually refer to short-term couplings, e.g. one-time dates at dances and parties, etc.

Another pair of terms I found is *inamorato* (male lover) and *inamorata* (female lover), but these words might be obscure.

Comment: Halfway between endearing and tongue-in-cheek, there's always Keith Mars' "special lady friend".

Answer (score 4):

Frankly, I think "girlfriend" is the best and most appropriate term. I've never understood it to imply that you are teenagers, and I really don't know any other widely-used term. There are some obsolete terms, like someone mentioned "beau" and "sweetheart", but I think these are pretty rarely used today. Well, if you're worried about sounding like you're trying to be trendy, maybe you consider sounding quaint and old-fashioned a  positive thing.

Answer (score 2):

A couple options:

- Significant other (helpfully, this seems to work for just about any relationship more *significant* than "just friends")
- Lady friend

Answer (score 2):

A few options to consider:

"Significant other" or "S.O.": A bit wordy, and the abbreviation probably would get a "huh?" in conversation.

"Partner": Ok, but people will read same-sex into it unless clarified.

Both of these have a "several years girlfriend" feel to them.

"Woman I'm Dating": Wordy, but not bad.

Comment: Yes, *partner* is particularly amusing when you know that your (opposite sex) partner is normally called by a shortened form of a name which would normally be assumed to be of the same gender. *8')

Answer (score 2):

I'm in my early thirties, and I most often use the word *lady* to describe my girlfriend.  As a note, though, I've used the same word since my early twenties.

However, I really see nothing wrong with using *girlfriend*, at any age.  No one will think you any less mature (or whatever else) because of it – I certainly won't.

Answer (score 2):

I'm rather fond of *squeeze* myself.

Answer (score 2):

Suggestions: beloved, sweetheart (Arabic: habibi) mi amore (Italian), my love, my darling, companion de vie (French, though not sure I spelled it correctly), honey. "Companion" seems common among retired people, but that can also be a weird euphemism or casts doubt on whether they even are or can be romantic, or whether they just like to travel together. "Fellow traveler" for science fiction fans. For long, "the other half of my heart." "Better half" is a humorous term and I have heard it used mostly by men to refer, in a complimentary way, either to their own wives or to their friends wives (also mild insult to the friend, but not necessarily).

"Significant Other" is actually a social science term, and it INCLUDES one's children, parents, really important friends or anyone who is personally quite important to one. I am a social scientist and I find this too broad, and also terribly unromantic. Though it is in common use. "Adult attachment figure" would be a psychological equivalent. Ick, right? Likewise, POSSLQ (poss-uh-queue): which I think stands for person of opposite sex sharing living quarters -- a term from the census. Distinctively impersonal unless tongue-in-cheek.

"Partner" is the term lots of people are using, to not exclude those in committed relationships who may or may not be married (was especially inclusive when or where gay & lesbian marriage was illegal. Its also gender-neutral and egalitarian. Personally I also don't like this because my connotation with partner is business partner or legal partner, and that again doesn't convey the lovingness and personal and emotional bonds of the relationships we are discussing. "Life partner" at least is better.

A few commentators do not seem to be distinguishing between how you would address one's beloved, and how one would refer to one's beloved to other people. Private and public terms can be different if you both want a private term or terms.

Comment: Girlfriend and boyfriend also imply that the other IS a girl or boy, and many adults now would like to be recognized as adults.

Answer (score 1):

You could say lady friend, but that sounds a bit disingenuous.  I think I would go with significant other, those that seems to imply marriage.  You could try describing the relationship instead of labeling it by saying that you're dating.

Comment: Lady-friend sounds close to ladybug. Cutsies

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest

"person I'm seeing" or "lady I'm seeing"

Comment: Despite the lack of attention this one has gotten, this actually seems like the one people might actually use to fit the situation. It's slightly euphemistic or vague, but you know that they are a couple, and avoids the age inappropriateness of 'boy/girl-friend'.

Answer (score 1):

The next best term is "significant other" but then you sound all-robotic-&-stuff.

After that, my "complementary gentle-being"....

Answer (score 1):

Also.
In scientific community *"a collaborator"* can now how this meaning.
(So, If you are talking with a scientist you better avoid the term.)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be "better half."

Answer (score 1):

> I'm in my mid 40s and dating this lady of a similar vintage. I am
>   trying to find a good word to describe our relationship, but
>   "girlfriend" and "boyfriend" seems inappropriate for us.

I find myself in a similar situation.

<sup>What follows is my very subjective and personal viewpoint. No doubt there will be some who will disagree with my interpretations, but I hope it explains why I (along with many other middle-aged people) share this dilemma.</sup>

I am 48 years old while my *boyfriend*, an Englishman, is only 57. It does sound a bit awkward when I talk about *my boyfriend* with friends and relatives, as neither of us are in our teens or twenties and for better or worse we normally associate *girl* and *boy* with young people.

I feel uncomfortable saying *partner* because we do not live together, and that term (for me) expresses a long-term commitment. I would use, *partner*, when you have been living together for a certain time, and the relationship is consolidated. As an expression, *partner*, is acceptable at any age, it's the unmarried equivalent of *spouse*.

I don't think my *boyfriend* has ever called me his *Lady friend* to anyone, and I have never heard him use that term within earshot. It lacks intimacy, and sounds old-fashioned, if he were to ever use that expression it would be in a humorous, jocular manner.

I have never been called a *mistress* in my life by any boyfriend, even when that man was married to someone else. But technically speaking, in an adulterous affair, the term, *mistress*, is appropriate. For this reason my current *boyfriend* (who is divorced) never calls me this, and I would object strongly if he ever did.

The term, *significant other*, I hate. I couldn't possibly bring myself to call any *boyfriend* that. It sounds horrible, and what does it mean? "This is the *other person* who plays a significant role in my life"! :)

However there is a term, which we call each other with affection and it works for us. ***Sweetie***. *You're my sweetie* is something we say to each other, and with very close friends it's a term that doesn't sound too sugary or cloying. I like being called *sweetie*. The term, *girlfriend*, is slowly growing on me but will I feel the same in my mid-fifties? I doubt it, unless of course he moves in, in which case I'd be happy to call him my *companion* or *partner* to anyone.