# Descriptor for people in an over 50 heterosexual relationship

Tags: word-choice

What is the best way to describe a relationship, or the two people in a relationship, who are heterosexual, non-married on purpose, but exclusive and committed, and over the age of 50, where “boyfriend” and “girlfriend” do not sound appropriate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a more concise term for a long-term girlfriend/boyfriend than "significant other"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76006/is-there-a-more-concise-term-for-a-long-term-girlfriend-boyfriend-than-signific) (There are a number of answers there, and also a number of other related questions link to that one, e.g. [Hesitation to use “girlfriend” in reference to old people](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38694/hesitation-to-use-girlfriend-in-reference-to-old-people))

Comment: You're not going to find anything that, in a single word, implies all of that. Least of all heterosexual or over fifty. (Or even exclusive.)

Comment: @sumelic I don't think that possible duplicate is an actual duplicate. That question looks for things where 'boyfriend/gorlfriend' is a legitimate answer. This question looks for terms that could be used by older people where 'boyfriend/girlfriend' is inappropriate-sounding (I think heterosexual is irrelevant).

Comment: @Mitch: How about [What is a synonym for “girlfriend”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31275/what-is-a-synonym-for-girlfriend) then? As I said, a lot of other posts link to that one; maybe one of the others is closer. But I think the answers to the different questions are all pretty similar

Comment: @sumelic Yes, _that_ link is much better and there are suggestions that work for the older set. Boyfriend-girlfriend still works for 30 year olds, but by 50 it just sounds childish. Whether that link is a duplicate is now moot.

Comment: Now that this question is closed, I'll answer in a comment: There's no good noun for it, 'boy/girl-friend' is the best but not great because of the weird teenager feeling. Instead use 'We're seeing each other' or 'that is the _person I'm seeing_'.

Answer (score -1):

“De facto husband/wife” or “de facto partner” would both work, derived from the fact that the sorts of relationships are often legally classified as de facto marriages.

Comment: *De facto husband/wife* is a narrower term than what the OP has in mind; it would be understood to imply that the two people live together.