# Is there an alternative term for "boyfriend" when talking about an elderly man?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, expressions

An acquaintance of mine referred to her mother, aged 95, as having a "boyfriend", aged 104, in their assisted living facility. I find this word in this context inappropriate.

I don't know what age an adult has to be before calling him/her a boy or girl outside their own immediate circle becomes inappropriate, but surely it is before they hit 100.

What is an age-appropriate term for boyfriend (girlfriend) for adults, especially adults of an advanced age?

There must be a word or phrase (borrowed from the French ?) to describe this lady's companion. **Cher ami** is not found even in the [OED](https://myvhc.virginiahospitalcenter.com/MyChartPRD/Signup), although the feminine form cherie amie is, with the definition "mistress".  (Same link.) In any case, cher ami is too obscure for most people.

**Companion** may be the best word, but I'm hoping that the perfect word or short phrase  exists, that conveys the romantic nature of the companionship, without calling an adult a boy.

**Companion**, according to [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/companion) is

> one that accompanies another : COMRADE, ASSOCIATE traveling companions
> also : one that keeps company with another his longtime companion

The [OED](https://www.oed.com/search?searchType=dictionary&q=companion&_searchBtn=Search) has a definition that encompasses lover or partner, which is, I suppose, a vote for companion. See Definition I.3.a.

**Why this is not a Duplicate:**  @Mitch pointed out that my question may possibly be a duplicate of [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38694/hesitation-to-use-girlfriend-in-reference-to-old-people).  The two are on the same topic, but approach it from opposite directions.  I am looking for an **age-appropriate substitute** for boyfriend (or girlfriend).  The other question wants **to validate girlfriend** for a woman in her sixties.   [Another similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31275/what-is-a-synonym-for-girlfriend) has many answers (along the lines of sweetie, significant other), of which only **beau** is a candidate IMO, that is, not there yet.

Comment: Great question but possibly a duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31275/what-is-a-synonym-for-girlfriend or https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38694/hesitation-to-use-girlfriend-in-reference-to-old-people. I'd prefer more answers in whatever location.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a synonym for "girlfriend"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31275/what-is-a-synonym-for-girlfriend)

Comment: I suspect that part of the difficulty here is the lack of definition for the thing you seek a term for. What exactly are the criteria for a "romantic character" in a relationship? A difference in sex between the parties is neither a necessary nor a sufficient condition, though the terms *boyfriend* and *girlfriend* would seem to be holdovers from a time when it was commonly assumed to be both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In most of the developed world, the traditional male-female courting towards and partnering of marriage has become cultural just one of many options. But in English at least the labels, nouns, verbs, or phrasing, really has not moved on much. Sure, people of all ages can have romantic relationships outside of marriage (and always have), but without the variety of nomenclature (at least in English) as for younger relationships. 'Boyfriend'/'girlfriend' just seem weird for people older than say ... 30? just because of the boy/girl part, even though the situation is mostly the same.

**Companion, partner, friend** all work fine, but they do have their primary, non-romantic meanings, and using them for romantic relationships, which people certainly do, always comes with some ambiguity nowadays: "Partner? Are they in business together? But they seem so close.". It always feels like there needs to be some disambiguation or a gesture or further explanation. Though these words have been used for romantic pairs, it is not (yet?) unambiguous even in context.

But as with all language, why is it necessary to force a single word onto things? That's what phrases are for. The seemingly empty but pragmatically accurate statement

> **"We're seeing each other"**

gets the point across without that weird gossipy stigma about it.

TL DR:

- Yes 'boyfriend' sounds childish
- Companion, partner, friend are fine and can be disambiguated with further explanation.
- "We're seeing each other" is how I would say it to avoid all the issues.

Comment: There is _a lot_ of commentary that could be made, going through all the alternatives and history (dating, going steady, 'her man'). As to loanwords (novio or petit ami) or archaic ones (swain or paramour or suitor) ...they all sound weird (or impenetrable or have the same incongruity of 
 youth in 'boyfriend').

Answer (score 13):

A possibility is "gentleman friend", which I have heard used in similar situations. It does not alway capture the distinction between "boy friend" and "boyfriend", but context can often clarify this. "Her gentleman friend" is more likely to correspond to boyfriend than "a gentleman friend".

For example

> Is there a significant other in Aunt Wilma's life yet? Yes, she is going out to dinner with her gentleman friend tonight.

Comment: We normally drop the gentle and just say **man friend** or **lady friend**.

Comment: @cup "man friend"? Really?

Comment: @cup out of curiosity what generation do most of the people in that “we” belong to? I have never heard “man friend” used in a serious way.

Comment: We - in the 60s.  The man/lady friends in the 60 to 80s.  Something like _your man friend has arrived_ or _is your lady friend coming over tonight_

Comment: @cup It just seems odd to use man/lady instead of man/woman or gentleman/lady. I guess gentleman is just one syllable too far :)

Comment: We also to use it when we are not sure whether they are just an acquaintance or someone closer.

Answer (score 4):

No, not really. There is a quote I've heard several times but can't quite put my finger on that addresses this, that criticizes English and its puritanical history as leaving it sorely lacking in adequate terminology for such things, thus forcing English speakers to use infantilizing misnomers like "boyfriend" and "girlfriend," along with odd euphemisms, and that's if there's a term at all, which there often isn't, like is actually the case here.

I mean, you could use a term like "gentleman caller," but only if you don't mind sounding like you're a character in Jane Austen novel and only if you don't mind that, while it does get rid of the infantilizing "boy" misnomer, it falls short of denoting the man is elderly, never mind how it may be a misnomer if the man isn't actually, by definition, a "gentleman." Like I said, English, because of the English's storied historical weirdness about sex and relationships, is sorely lacking in adequate terminology for such things, a veritable famine.

Comment: I think *gentleman caller* is more Tennessee Williams *(The Glass Menagerie)* than Jane Austen.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this is a bit of aside but...the use of ‘boyfriend’ in such situations is usually intended as humourous. Another such term is ‘lover boy’. Affections can run deep in aged care, but holding hands and gazing wistfully is about as far as things can go. I doubt offence would be taken. Perhaps ask the centenarian himself; I bet he’d be tickled by the term.

Comment: +1 for "ask the centenarian".  Always good to use the term the person prefers.  But I would add, ask the mother, too.  She may not like the term boyfriend, although he does.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason one couldn’t use “beau” in this context ?
While it may be somewhat dated, that could be construed as making it more appropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

One word I've actually heard used in this situation (a little younger than yours but still plenty old, the two were in their 70s) is "fella", as in "Is it okay if I bring my fella George along?" Similar from the other side would be "gal".

Answer (score 1):

I like *beau*, but it's a little problematic in that it has no feminine equivalent. And *fella* works when the person in the relationship is speaking of his-her-their,  well, fella, but it sounds too familiar if someone else is speaking of him (*my mother and her fella attended an interesting lecture*).

*The man my mother is seeing* is only three syllables longer than *my mother's boyfriend*, and that expenditure is worthwhile bc it avoids the latter's infantilizing quality.

Comment: Belle is the feminine of beau in French.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little puzzled here. I had an English girlfriend once, whose mother called me her daughter's **fiancé**.

Yet I see no suggestion to this title.
(I'm not a native English speaker, so maybe I have misunderstood something).

Comment: fiancé means you're engaged to be married, so only applies if that's actually true

Comment: Her mother was hinting.