# how should I name the man I live with?

Tags: single-word-requests

(From a foreign speaker : )
I'm lucky enough to live with the man I love, but we're not married, nor having any "official" marital life. How should I refer to him ?
He's a divorced man and will never be a "husband" again, and I don't feel like using the word "boyfriend" since both of us are over 50 ! The American "partner" sounds a bit too "raw" to me, and the Canadian "chum" doesn't befit the man either. 
I sometimes need to refer to him when talking to British as well as American guests.

Comment: What do you mean by *"partner" sounds a bit too "raw" to me*? I think it's now the standard term in the UK on official documents in contexts where a [live-in] partner is treated on the same basis as a [married] spouse. If you want something a bit more "twee", you might like ***significant other***, but you probably wouldn't want to use that on an official document.

Comment: _Partner_ is the standard term in the US, to the extent there is one -- this is a new thing, societally. And there's nothing "raw" about it. I enjoy being single and living with my partner. I've been married and had a wife once; my partner is not my wife, and we both like it that way, and she uses _partner_ just like I do.

Comment: Please let us know which term you found most appropriate. I find calling my 57-year-old man, a boyfriend, slightly awkward too :) But the term *partner*, I feel, is perfect if you are living together.

Comment: also related: [Is there a more concise term for a long-term girlfriend/boyfriend than “significant other”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/76006/is-there-a-more-concise-term-for-a-long-term-girlfriend-boyfriend-than-signific?lq=1) and [What is a synonym for “girlfriend”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31275/what-is-a-synonym-for-girlfriend?lq=1)